# How can I make a form application which has ruler and page border?

Tags: forms, visual-studio

I am trying to make a form application in Visual Studio 2022 VB.Net. I want to add a ruler and page border as shown below picture. How could I do this?

[image]

Comment: Hi! At this site, we require you to at least try to solve the problem yourself first. As it is the question is too broad. Try to solve this yourself and when you run into a problem, add your code as [mcve] and explain in detail what is not working as you intend.

Comment: I know the rules you reminded me of. I don't expect anyone to write code for me. I would expect a friend who knows about this subject to provide a link or share any code.

Comment: You don't expect anyone to write you code but to give you the code? What is the difference? If you know the rules, please provide [mcve] of your implementation and explain what problems you are facing.

Comment: Okay, I will make a minimal reproducible example as much as possible